# update value inside the nested document in MongoDB ( pymongo )

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

how to update a value in the database using MongoDB and python

Following is the schema of the document I want to update:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5e8c8f19efd3d269180afdf6'), 
 'student': 2, 
 'sem': 
 [
     {
         'sem_2': {
              'c': 90, 
              'c++': 98, 
              'java': 82, 
              'go': 96, 
              'python': 99
                 }
        }, 

      {
          'sem_1': {
              'daa': 90, 
              'dbms': 70, 
              'es': 79, 
              '.net': 89, 
              'ds': 88
          }
      }
 ]

}
```

I want to update the "sem_1" value in the document.

```
{

          'sem_1': {
              'daa': 99, 
              'dbms': 99, 
              'es': 99, 
              '.net': 99, 
              'ds': 99
          }

}
```

I need output like

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5e8c8f19efd3d269180afdf6'), 
 'student': 2, 
 'sem': 
 [
     {
         'sem_2': {
              'c': 90, 
              'c++': 98, 
              'java': 82, 
              'go': 96, 
              'python': 99
                 }
        }, 

      {
          'sem_1': {
              'daa': 99, 
              'dbms': 99, 
              'es': 99, 
              '.net': 99, 
              'ds': 99
          }
      }
 ]

}
```

I'm using PyMongo, is there a way to update this kind of document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using positional [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/index.html) operator in MongoDB :

```
db.collection.updateOne(
  { student: 2, "sem.sem_1": { $exists: true } }, // You need to have this `sem.sem_1` check in order to make `$` work
  {
    $set: {
      "sem.$": {
        sem_1: {
          daa: 99,
          dbms: 99,
          es: 99,
          ".net": 99,
          ds: 99,
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
```

In **pymongo** :

You can do the same using [.update_one()](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=update_one#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) :

```
db.collection.update_one({ student: 2, "sem.sem_1": { $exists: true } }, 
      {
        $set: {
          "sem.$": {
            sem_1: {
              daa: 99,
              dbms: 99,
              es: 99,
              ".net": 99,
              ds: 99,
            }
          }
        }
      })
```

**Note :** As `update_one` would return [WriteResult](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/index.html) instead of document, if you wanted to return actual document then try [.find_one_and_update()](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=find_one_and_update#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_update)